# WUA DatePicker or CalendarDatePicker Control Limit to Particular Week Day?

Tags: wpf, datepicker, calendar, windows-10-universal

I am developing Windows 10 Universal app. I need a date picker which is only providing Tuesdays as available choices for picking. Can that be set up using the DatePicker or CalendarDatePicker control or should I rather go and implement something on my own?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, we agreed with the client to withhold this request

Comment: Okay, because i searched for an alternative solution. Thx anyway